# How to make the draggable content stick inside the boundaries of the box composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using a draggable content in which I want the image or the box in below code to stick within the boundaries of the box composable while dragging not move out to the parent Column composable as shown in the image below how to achieve it [image: example image]

```
  @Composable
 private fun 
  DraggableTextLowLevel() {
 
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()).   {
Text("Custom Edit Place")
Box(modifier = Modifier.hieght(200.dp).width(300.dp) {
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .size(50.dp)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()
                    offsetX += dragAmount.x
                    offsetY += dragAmount.y
                }
            }
    )
}
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keep the draggable content inside the parent layout boundaries, the offset of the draggable content itself must be in a range within the layout boundaries.

The boundaries can be obtained by using the `onPlaced` modifier applied to the parent layout. This modifier provides the coordinates of the layout after it has been placed and before its children. This allows the children to adjust their own placement based on where the parent is.

```kotlin
// The size of the parent layout used later on to determine the
// offset of the draggable content inside the parent boundaries.

var parentSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(200.dp)
        .width(300.dp)
        .background(Color.LightGray)
        .onPlaced { layoutCoordinates ->

            // Set the [parentSize] to the size
            // of the layout in the local coordinates space.

            parentSize = layoutCoordinates.size.toSize()

        }
) ...
```

One example of keeping the draggable content inside the parent layout boundaries is by keeping the `offsetX` and `offsetY` values to a range within the corresponding bounds.

```kotlin
var draggableContentSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
var offsetX by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
var offsetY by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .onPlaced { draggableContentSize = it.size.toSize() }
        .offset { IntOffset(x = offsetX.roundToInt(), y = offsetY.roundToInt()) }
        .background(Color.Blue)
        .size(50.dp)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                change.consume()

                // Keep the [offsetX] value inside the parent
                // width boundary by allowing it be in a range between
                // 0 and the parent width - draggableContentSize width.

                offsetX = (offsetX + dragAmount.x).coerceIn(
                    minimumValue = 0f,
                    maximumValue = parentSize.width - draggableContentSize.width
                )

                // Keep the [offsetY] value inside the parent
                // height boundary by allowing it be in a range between
                // 0 and the parent height - draggableContentSize height.

                offsetY = (offsetY + dragAmount.y).coerceIn(
                    minimumValue = 0f, 
                    maximumValue = parentSize.height - draggableContentSize.height
                )

            }
        }
)
```

Here is a visual demonstration of the example.

[image: A visual demonstration of the given example.]

Happy coding!

Comment: can you help me with this question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77665556/how-to-make-the-multitouch-panning-zooming-rotating-place-inside-the-box-comp/77665584?noredirect=1#comment136927173_77665584" thanks