# How to make the Multitouch: Panning, zooming, rotating place inside the box compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want the Drag and zoom to be done inside the box composable and not to move out to the Column parent composable how to make it stick inside the box composable alone

```
@Composable
private fun TransformableSample() {
// set up all transformation states
var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
var rotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
val state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, offsetChange, rotationChange ->
    scale *= zoomChange
    rotation += rotationChange
    offset += offsetChange
}
Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
    Text(text = "MultiTouch Zoom Preview", fontSize = 26.sp)
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(25.dp))
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.DarkGray)
        .height(200.dp)
        .width(350.dp)){
        Box(
            Modifier

                .padding(start = 20.dp)
                .graphicsLayer(
                    scaleX = scale,
                    scaleY = scale,
                    rotationZ = rotation,
                    translationX = offset.x,
                    translationY = offset.y
                )

                .transformable(state = state)
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .size(120.dp)
        )
    }
}
}
```

[image: moving out of the grey background box]

Answer (score 2):

You can add `Modifier.clipToBounds` to Modifier parent(DarkGray) Box if you wish to clip anything that is drawn out of that Composable. In jetpack compose without clipping you can draw anywhere out of any Composable.

### Edit

If you wish to check if a zoomed, rotated, and translated rectangle is inside another Rectangle bounds you can do it with a `Path` that contains physical information of this Composable as well. When you scale use `Matrix` scale, rotate and translate and using difference between parent `Path` and child `Path` as in this answer you will be able to limit rectangle inside parent.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77579871/5457853

Comment: But it's like if I move to any corner of the parent Box half of the blue box sliding in and other half is visible .can you please give any other suggestions to not move out the box thanks

Comment: The GitHub project of yours I got to know https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter6_graphics/Tutorial6_6EditBox.kt. Can you help with that to i tried using Modifier.clipToBounds

Comment: This is a very good question but in first part rotating an item  with your current function without setting proper centroid position will result as in my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922205/how-to-have-natural-pan-and-zoom-with-modifier-graphicslayer-pointerinput

Comment: But to limit your child Composable in parent you can use 2 paths and check the difference as in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77579871/5457853. Simply apply scale, rotation and translation to a Matrix of child path(blue rectangle) and check on each drag and check difference as i do for checking which section of map is touched.